# Movie about a guy who has a camera and can control time

Tags: story-identification, movie

I think this is a movie from around 2005-2010. I can only remember few scenes from the movie and I'm not even sure if they are in the same movie.

From what I recall, the protagonist is 30+ year old man who has a camera. I'm not sure how to classify it but the camera is like the same one that's used to film a movie but somewhat smaller. I'm not sure if it's a digital camera but I know it's slightly bigger than that. Now, this camera can pause the time.

One scene that I can recall is that this guy saw a mugging/criminal situation between a man pinning a woman (not sure) in an alley and he paused the camera so he can examine the situation better. He saw a policeman near an intersection and he lifted the cop near the situation and unpaused the time. I know that the the guy in the alley is actually stopping the woman with a knife but instead, the woman stopped the struggle and managed to stab/slash the policeman and ran away.

Another scene that I remember is the guy with the camera paused a car accident in which a car with friends are on collision (or collided) with a woman whose face smashed the windshield while calling someone. He saw the picture of the person (who I think is a woman) in the phone and tried to find her to tell her what happened.

And then this is where it gets tricky because I'm not sure if it's the same film or not. The woman was tied up on a chair and tried to run away from the guy who have the camera. The guy, I think, is trying to save the woman from something or someone (at least what my mother told me).

The last scene that I remember was that the woman managed to kill the man with the camera by pushing him accidentally into the stairs and getting impaled by a chair's leg that turned upside down.

Now, I am not entirely sure if they are in the same movie. But yes, these are the scenes that I distinctly remember from the movie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this ***[Suspension](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0989760/)*** (2008)...?

> **Daniel loses his wife and son in a car accident. While slowly recovering from his injuries, he rebuilds his son's video camera that was destroyed in the crash. Infused with power from the moment of the crash, the camera develops the ability to stop time when Daniel presses the pause button.** This discovery restores Daniel's purpose, and he fills the vacuum in his life by taking responsibility for another victim, Sarah, a newlywed who lost her husband in the same accident. At first Daniel only watches her, then tries to improve her life in small ways. But using his power to "help" becomes an addiction, and the vastness of Daniel's power can do only one thing...corrupt him.

Comment: WOW, YES! I think this is it! I thought the person calling was a woman but apparently, he's the husband of the girl on the phone. I vaguely remember the movie since I was a kid back then. 2008 is in track on what year it was.  I'll have to watch it again. Thank you for answering!